# Wordpress customizing with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to edit my wordpress website CSS style  using the dashboard. I only can login using admin password and username but I dont have the website file. Where I should write the CSS statements ?

Comment: I googled *wordpress custom css* and [this was the first result](http://wordpress.com/products/custom-css/). It appears to answer your question perfectly. Was there anything else you needed?

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard - Appearance - Editor - style.css

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to edit the CSS of a blog hosted by wordpress, follow these directions:

1. go to Appearance → Customize → CSS in your blog dashboard.
2. You will be able to add custom CSS here.
3. Make sure you save your changes, then refresh your page.
   [This site has a detailed description of how to do this.](http://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/)

The directions are more complex if you wish to add a custom stylesheet to your theme. Just based on the question alone, i'm assuming that wordpress.com is hosting your blog though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel-> appearance->Editor->style.css will appear on right hand side.